# is jQuery's .css() method actually CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When using jQuery's .css() method, it applies an inline style.  Inline styles are literally the *opposite* of Cascading Style Sheets.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, it's not actually CSS, it's javascript, and it does set inline styles, and those are valid CSS.

Comment: And Cascading Style Sheets is a  style sheet language, and HTML supports `style` attributes **and** tags, that can contain that language.

Comment: Why are they the opposite of CSS? o.0

Comment: I guess I define CSS as something that appears in a .css file, but maybe that's the part I was misunderstanding.  It looks to me that inline styles are actually defined as being part of the cascade.

I just have a personal vendetta against inline styles, and I'm surprised that jQuery thinks they are a good idea.

Comment: styles still cascade from the element they are applied to inline, so no idea why you say they are ***opposite***

Answer (score 0):

The .css() method is a convenient way to get or set a computed style property of a DOM element. The computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet, see the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more details